# Easiest way to serialize an ValueTuple list

Tags: c#, list, serialization, tuples, valuetuple

What's the easiest way to serialize and de-serialize an List<(string,string)>? , something that can be stored into an string column in an database table.

Comment: You could serialize it to JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSON. Firstly you need to download the Newtonsoft.Json package. Visual studio > Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console. Next, paste *Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 13.0.1* to console. Next, create FileHelper class and use this code.

Package link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
namespace Json
{
    static class FileHelper
    {
        public static void JsonSerialize(object obj, string fileName)
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter($"{fileName}.json"))
            {
                using (var jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    jw.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
                    serializer.Serialize(jw, obj);
                }
            }
        }
        public static void JsonDeserialize(out object obj, string fileName)
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader($"{fileName}.json"))
            {
                using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                {
                    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    try
                    {
                        obj = serializer.Deserialize<object>(jr);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        obj = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```